# How to set i.p for usb0 before imx board boots?

Tags: usb, yocto, ifconfig, imx6

I'd like to automatically set the i.p address of usb port which is configured in cdc mode for my imx6 board.

I have tried manually setting the

I have also written a script to do this after boot.
(after we login as root).

Both of them work but I'd like this to happen before the board asks for login prompt.

This was the content of the script

```
ifconfig usb0 192.168.100.100
```

placed in /etc/profile.d

I need to first login as root and then I can see the ip of usb0.
Is it possible to have usb0's i.p set before login?

Comment: Do you use systemd or sysvinit?

Comment: I use systemd on my board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a script 
/etc/rc.local

It was mentioned that the script does nothing so I guess that means I can modify it as I wish.

I just added

```
ifconfig usb0 192.168.100.100
```

at the start, and the usb i.p seem's to have set before login.

This however seems like a dirty solution, If there is a cleaner way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `meta-custom/recipes-core/systemd-conf/files/06-usb0.network` file:

```
[Match]
Name=usb0

[Network]
Address=192.168.100.100/24
```

With `meta-custom/recipes-core/systemd-conf/systemd-conf_%.bbappend` recipe:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI += "file://06-usb0.network"

do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/network
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/06-usb0.network ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/network
}

FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/systemd/network/06-usb0.network"
```

Note: if you don't use latest Yocto release, it should be `systemd-conf.bbappend` instead of `systemd-conf_%.bbappend`

Comment: what does_% stand for in systemd-conf_%.bbappend (I'm a novice so I'm not familiar with the jargon)

Comment: `When you name an append file, you can use the "%" wildcard character to allow for matching recipe names.` see [mega manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-terms)